# Printing data from DB in WordPress not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to print data from the database to WordPress. However, it is not working as expected. I also tried to print a simple variable.

```
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // username
$password=""; // password
$db_name="bk"; // Database name
// Replace database connect functions depending on database you are using.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$tbl_nm="rg";
global $wpdb;
$a=6;
$B=9;
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT nm FROM rg" );
foreach ( $result as $print )   {
?><tr><td><?php
echo $print->nm;
print $a+$B;
?></td>
</tr>
<?php }
```

Comment: You code makes zero sense. You're using `mysql_connect` (at least use `mysqli`) and then try to query with `wpdb` connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> hey,,i sloved my problem actually i m not assign 'mysql_connect()'  to any veriable
>
> here is my code

```
  $host="localhost"; // Host name
  $username="root"; // username
  $password=""; // password
  $db_name="bk"; // Database name

  // Replace database connect functions depending on database you are using.
  $con=mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password","$db_name");



     $tbl_nm="rg";
     global $wpdb;
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM rg" );
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {echo '    <td colspan="0">'.$row['nm'].'</td>';}
    ?>
```